# What happends with @Async. Does it time out?

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-3

Say I have an `@Async` method call that hangs. Will it time out? What is best practise here to free you resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Async` method invocations are executed within a specified thread pool. If your method hangs, it will hold one thread from the pool infinitely. Spring can't do anything about it.

If your method is kind enough to accept `InterruptedException`, you can cancel it by calling [`Future.cancel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) on a value returned from asynchronous method.

Comment: Can you please give me some more information about this. Future is the return value? How will I then know if an exception occured?

Comment: Please read the JavaDocs of [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) carefully, `Future.get()` throws an exception if it was thrown from task.

Comment: Thanks. You that solved it. get(time, TimeUnit) throws an exception. In the catch or finally we can call cancel.

Comment: @user874774: no, you are misunderstanding something. When `get()` returns or throws, the task has already completed. Calling `cancel()` doesn't make much sense then.